# How can I extract the multiple attributes that are the same, from an XML node in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I currently have an XML file from a Garmin Sat Nav, which I want to extract data from using Java. However, I cannot find a way to extract the TRACK latitudes and longitudes, because there are multiple attributes with the same name, within a single node. I thought of using something like "getAttribute("lat")", but apparntly this would only return the first latitude of the first track segment :-(

I haven't yet started the project, because it is crucial that I extract the latitudes and longitudes from the XML file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

XML FILE

```
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3"
xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" creator="Oregon
400t" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1
http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd 
http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3
http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd
http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1
http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd">
<metadata>
  <link href="http://www.garmin.com">
    <text>Garmin International</text>
  </link>
    <time>2009-10-17T22:58:43Z</time>
</metadata>
<trk>
<name>Example GPX Document</name>
<trkseg>
  <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
    <ele>4.46</ele>
    <time>2009-10-17T18:37:26Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
    <ele>4.94</ele>
    <time>2009-10-17T18:37:31Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
    <ele>6.87</ele>
    <time>2009-10-17T18:37:34Z</time>
  </trkpt>
</trkseg>
```

Hi, I tried the below code, but for some reason I'm retrieving a value, that I can't even find in my XML file!!!

```
package Test;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class ReadXMLFile2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(new File("J:/Desktop/Current.gpx"));

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    System.out.println(xpath.evaluate("//trkseg/trkpt/@lat", document));
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to use XPath you first need to make your `DocumentBuilderFactory` namespace-aware (annoyingly it isn't by default, presumably for historical reasons) since the XPath language requires namespace support.

Now the `xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"` at the top of your XML file means that all the unprefixed element names in the document belong to that namespace.  In order to match them with XPath you will therefore need to define a `NamespaceContext` that binds this namespace URI to a prefix and use that prefix consistently in the XPath expressions.

Alternatively it may be simpler to forget XPath and just use the standard DOM APIs:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
// enable namespace processing
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse(new File("J:/Desktop/Current.gpx"));

NodeList trkpts = document.getElementsByTagNameNS(
           "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1", "trkpt");
for(int i = 0; i < trkpts.getLength(); i++) {
  Element pt = (Element)trkpts.item(i);
  // since namespaces are enabled we must use the DOM level 2 getAttributeNS,
  // not the legacy getAttribute, even though the attributes we're getting
  // do not themselves belong to a namespace.
  System.out.println("lat: " + pt.getAttributeNS(null, "lat") +
      ", long: " + pt.getAttributeNS(null, "lon"));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, that was the exact answer I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

Read up on XPath: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

For example, to get the lat attribute from the last trkpt, you could use the path

`/gpx/trk/trkseg[last()]/@lat`

Comment: Hi thank you for replying. Just one other question, it possible to select a particular track point latitude, rather than just selecting the first or last one?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try an [XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) query for the attributes something like `/trkseg/trkpt/@lat` to get all the latitudes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I seem to be getting some value back, but its not what I was expecting, please could you check the code that I added to the post please.

Comment: Okay I think the XML file is at fault here, when I use other XML files, I always get the result that I'm expecting. However, is it possible to select a particular track point latitude, rather than just selecting the first one. Many Thanks

Comment: @user3379365 yes it is possible to select a specific latitude if you know which one you want, e.g. `/trkseg/trkpt/@lat[2]`