# How to select all attribute values from a particular attribute using xpath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following XML file containing GPS co-ordinates, and I was just wondering how I can extract the track latitudes and longitudes using Xpath in Java. So far I tried:

```
System.out.println(xpath.evaluate("/gpx/trk/trkseg/trkpt/@lat", doc));
```

but this only retrieves the first value? Please can someone tell me how to retrieve all the values in one go.

Many Thanks in advance.

```
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creator="MapSource 6.11.3"
version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1
http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
<metadata>...</metadata>
<wpt lat="40.653792" lon="-111.922379">...</wpt>
<wpt lat="40.658111" lon="-111.919564">...</wpt>
<wpt lat="40.659546" lon="-111.917527">...</wpt>
<wpt lat="40.595857" lon="-111.910294">...</wpt>
<wpt lat="40.657349" lon="-111.918721">...</wpt>
<trk>
<name>FromParking</name>
<extensions>...</extensions>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="40.653782" lon="-111.922365">
    <ele>1224.376221</ele>
    <time>2009-11-19T20:00:11Z</time>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="40.653786" lon="-111.922350">
    <ele>1223.895508</ele>
    <time>2009-11-19T20:00:13Z</time>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="40.654449" lon="-111.922073">
    <ele>1224.376221</ele>
    <time>2009-11-19T20:00:22Z</time>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="40.654509" lon="-111.921919">
    <ele>1224.376221</ele>
    <time>2009-11-19T20:00:25Z</time>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="40.654618" lon="-111.921700">
    <ele>1224.856934</ele>
    <time>2009-11-19T20:00:35Z</time>
</trkpt>
```

Comment: What XML/XPath library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the namespaces issue I described in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22197740/592139), your fundamental problem here is that the `XPath.evaluate` methods *without* a `QName returnType` parameter will evaluate the XPath expression *as a string*, and the XPath rules say that the string value of a node set containing more than one node is [defined to be](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) the string value of the *first* node in the set in document order.

If you want to evaluate XPath expressions that return a set of nodes then you must use one of the XPath methods that takes a QName, pass `XPathConstants.NODESET` as the requested return type, and cast the result returned from `evaluate` to a `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` which you can then iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: to retrieve all `trkpt` attributes do this:

```
String trkpt ="/gpx/trk/trkseg/trkpt";
NodeList nodeList= (NodeList) xpath.compile(trkpt).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++){
   Node node = nodeList.item(i);
   NamedNodeMap attributesMap = node.getAttributes();

   for (int j = 0; j< attributesMap.getLength(); j++) {            
     Node attributeNode = attributesMap.item(j);       
     String attributeName = attributeNode.getNodeName();        
     String attributeValue = attributeNode.getNodeValue();

     System.out.println(attributeName + "=" + attributeValue);
   }
}
```